# Downloading large files from artifactory remote repo giving error - unexpected EOF

Tags: artifactory, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have an artifactory in Jfrog, where the vendor keeps the updated binaries. I am supposed to download the binaries using a build task (i.e. Artifactory Generic Download) from Azure Pipelines. While downloading the binaries from that artifactory remote repo some large files(i.e. more that 800 MB in size) are not getting downloaded and throwing an error "unexpected EoF"

I thought the issue was because of slow internet, so I had tried to download those artifacts with fastest internet connection available, but it did not help.

The output I got was this

```
##[debug]fileSpec={
    "files": [
        {
            "pattern": "Dependencies/SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU.exe",
            "target": "D:\Abhijit\VSTS_Agent\_work\2\s\\"
        }
    ]
}
Using file spec:
{
    "files": [
        {
            "pattern": "Dependencies/SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU.exe",
            "target": "D:\\Abhijit\\VSTS_Agent\\_work\\2\\s\\"
        }
    ]
}
##[debug]0a364c9c-b6a0-43eb-8b47-d6a58c68b016 auth param username = ***
##[debug]0a364c9c-b6a0-43eb-8b47-d6a58c68b016 auth param password = ***
##[debug]failNoOp=true
##[debug]buildName=Test_Project_KT-CI (1)
##[debug]buildNumber=309
[Info] Searching items to download...
[Info] [Thread 2] Downloading Dependencies/SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU.exe
[Info] [Thread 2] [0]: 206 Partial content...
[Info] [Thread 2] [1]: 206 Partial Content...
[Info] [Thread 2] [2]: 206 Partial Content...
[Warn] [Thread 2] [1]: Attempt 0 - Failure occurred while downloading part 1 of https://artifacts.test.com/artifactory/Dependencies/SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU.exe - unexpected EOF
[Warn] [Thread 2] [2]: Attempt 0 - Failure occurred while downloading part 2 of https://artifacts.test.com/artifactory/Dependencies/SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU.exe - unexpected EOF
[Info] [Thread 2] [1]: 206 Partial Content...
[Warn] [Thread 2] [1]: Attempt 1 - Failure occurred while downloading part 1 of https://artifacts.test.com/artifactory/Dependencies/SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU.exe - unexpected EOF
[Info] [Thread 2] [1]: 206 Partial Content...
[Info] [Thread 2] [2]: 206 Partial Content...
[Warn] [Thread 2] [2]: Attempt 1 - Failure occurred while downloading part 2 of https://artifacts.test.com/artifactory/Dependencies/SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU.exe - unexpected EOF
[Warn] [Thread 2] [1]: Attempt 2 - Failure occurred while downloading part 1 of https://artifacts.test.com/artifactory/Dependencies/SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU.exe - unexpected EOF
[Info] [Thread 2] [1]: 206 Partial Content...
[Info] [Thread 2] [2]: 206 Partial Content...
[Warn] [Thread 2] [2]: Attempt 2 - Failure occurred while downloading part 2 of https://artifacts.test.com/artifactory/Dependencies/SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU.exe - unexpected EOF
[Warn] [Thread 2] [1]: Attempt 3 - Failure occurred while downloading part 1 of https://artifacts.test.com/artifactory/Dependencies/SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU.exe - unexpected EOF
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xc0000005 code=0x0 addr=0x10 pc=0x799657]
```

expected Output

````
##[debug]fileSpec={
    "files": [
        {
            "pattern": "Dependencies/SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU.exe",
            "target": "D:\Abhijit\VSTS_Agent\_work\2\s\\"
        }
    ]
}
Using file spec:
{
    "files": [
        {
            "pattern": "Dependencies/SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU.exe",
            "target": "D:\\Abhijit\\VSTS_Agent\\_work\\2\\s\\"
        }
    ]
}
##[debug]0a364c9c-b6a0-43eb-8b47-d6a58c68b016 auth param username = ***
##[debug]0a364c9c-b6a0-43eb-8b47-d6a58c68b016 auth param password = ***
##[debug]failNoOp=true
##[debug]buildName=Test_Project_KT-CI (1)
##[debug]buildNumber=309
[Info] Searching items to download...
[Info] [Thread 2] Downloading Dependencies/SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU.exe
[Info] [Thread 2] [0]: 206 Partial content...
[Info] [Thread 2] [1]: 206 Partial Content...
[Info] [Thread 2] [2]: 206 Partial Content...
[Info] download done...
```
````

Comment: Did you try downloading the same file using cURL or any other client? are you seeing the same behavior?

Comment: Hi Dror. I tried to download the files directly from the jforgs UI. It was being downloaded in my machine in this way.

Answer (score 1):

According to your output file, not only `unexpected EOF`, you also got another error message:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xc0000005 code=0x0 addr=0x10 pc=0x799657]
```

This is the error which about `Go`, and [the task you used](https://github.com/jfrog/jfrog-client-go/blob/master/artifactory/services/download.go) is written with this Go language.  According to their github repos, you can check what the task code is. So this error message should caused by their task code, not you.

In addition, There also have similar error under their github issue report. You can check [it](https://github.com/jfrog/jfrog-client-go/pull/40). Their team are updating to change the code which cause this error and their latest release will include this change.